# как мне отобразить картинку из базы данных используя freemaker?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker, хостинг-изображений

Я собираюсь деплоить приложение на heroku и для меня легкий выход это хранить изображения в БД.
Но у меня не получается отобразить картинку, которую я сохраняю в БД.

Одна из ошибок которая отображется:

```
freemarker.core.NonStringOrTemplateOutputException: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence):
==> message.img  [in template "main.ftlh" at line 69, column 89]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${message.img}  [in template "main.ftlh" at line 69, column 87]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "parts/common.ftlh" in macro "page" at line 17, column 5]
    ~ Reached through: @c.page  [in template "main.ftlh" at line 3, column 1]
----
```

так я пытаюсь отобразить картинку в `main.ftl`:

```
<#if message.img??>
   <img class="card-img-top" src="/img/${message.img}" alt="Card image cap" style="width:100%">
</#if>
```

Entity выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Entity
public class Message {
...код...

@Lob
    private byte[] img;

...код...
}
```

В контролере я получаю файл с помощью:

```
@PostMapping("/main")
    public String add(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
            @Valid Message message,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model,
            @RequestParam("file")MultipartFile file
    ) throws IOException {
        message.setAuthor(user);

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            Map<String, String> errorsMap = ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);

            model.addAttribute("message", message);
            model.mergeAttributes(errorsMap);
        } else {
            if (file != null && !file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()) {
                message.setImg(file.getBytes());
            }

            model.addAttribute("message", null);
            messageRepo.save(message);
        }

        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("messages",messages);
        return "main";
    }
```

Прошу помощи и указать на ошибки.
Понимаю, что это путь `src="/img/${message.img}"`, но не знаю, как отобразить картинку напрямую из БД. Как мне лучше сделать

Comment: Ну а прилепить не получается?

Comment: @Roman C Прилепить что?

Comment: ${message.img} к <img>

Comment: все равно не совсем понимаю. <img class="card-img-top" src="${message.img}">. Так я пробовал. Не получалось, по другому не знаю как сделать

Comment: Так делать нельзя, т.к. FM не понимает значение внутри ${} и все что находится внутри должно быть типа стринг.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что так нельзя. А как тогда сделать? <img>message.img</img>?

Comment: Так тоже не работает, но непонятно почему.

Comment: ну дык...вы сохраняете содержимое картинки, а в верстке указываете ссылку в которую пытаетесь вставить содержимое изображения....оно так не работает. либо сохраняйте в ФС данные картинки и в БД храните путь до нее на сервере, либо нужно отдельный контроллер сделать который будет отдавать это изображение, и в верстке уже его указывать.

Answer (score 1):

## В чем проблема?

Атрибут `src` тега `<img/>` предназначен для того, чтобы указывать в нём ссылку на изображение.
Это значит, что браузер может получить строку из этого атрибута и используя данную строку как адрес, браузер может отправить HTTP запрос, на который ожидает получить 200-ый HTTP ответ с содержимым картинки в теле ответа.

Нельзя просто взять и указать

```
src="/img/${message.img}"
```

и надеяться на то, что приложение само за вас настроит маршрутизацию и отдачу  контента с сервера.

Вы просто пытаетесь вставить массив байтов в верстку.
Эти данные будут в лучшем случае преобразованы в строку.
Как будет выглядеть подобная строка, вы можете поинтересоваться открыв любое изображение в блокноте.

> **Спойлер:** нет!
> судя по исключению FreeMaker не смог автоматически конвертировать массив байтов в строку
> Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean)

## Что делать?

### 1. Нужно реализовать отдачу изображений

Для этого добавьте в контроллер метод, который получает из БД сообщение и возвращает его содержимое в виде HTTP-ответа.

Т.к. нам нужно будет искать изображения в БД, было бы неплохо как-то получать идентификатор записи из запроса.

**Для этого:**

- укажите в шаблоне пути плейсхолдер `{id}`
- для перехвата значения из шаблона пути объявите параметр `Long id` и пометьте его аннотацией `@PathVariable("id")` для того чтобы связать его с плейсхолдером
- пометьте метод контроллера аннотацией `@ResponseBody`, чтобы использовать возвращаемое методом значение в качестве тела HTTP ответа
- для того чтобы спринг сформировал корректные HTTP-заголовки, соответствующие типу отдаваемого контента, укажите в аннотации `@GetMapping` атрибут `produces` со значением `MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE` для PNG или `MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE` для JPEG изображений
- с помощью репозитория получите из БД запись по идентификатору
- обязательно проверьте наличие записи в результатах поиска и наличие содержимого изображения в записи
- верните содержимое изображения, в противном случае выкиньте исключение с 404 ошибкой

```java
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/img/messages/{id}.png", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public byte[] img(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Optional<Message> messageSearchResult = messageRepo.findById(id);
    if(messageSearchResult.isPresent()) {
        Message message = messageSearchResult.get();
        if (message.getImg() != null  && message.getImg().length > 0){
            return message.getImg();
        }
    }
    // если выполнение дошло до данной строки, значит ничего не было найдено
    // выбрасываем 404
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Image Not Found");
}
```

### Формируем и указываем в шаблоне корректную ссылку на изображение

Далее указываем в шаблоне ссылку, соответствующую шаблону пути из вышеуказанного метода и пробрасываем в него идентификатор сообщения

```
<#if message.img??>
   <img class="card-img-top" src="/img/messages/${message.id}.png" alt="Card image cap" style="width:100%">
</#if>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваш ответ навел меня на правильное решение! 
К сожалению, просто добавив ваш код у меня ничего не вышло, но я посидел два часа, чуть подкоректировал, что то покрутил, погуглил и теперь картинки отображаются. В "ответ на собственный вопрос" добавлю, что получилось.
Главное вы донесли основную мысль) как я понял, нужно поместить картинку в Servlet было и ссылаться на нее во view. Я даже не знал что так можно сделать)
Огромная благодраность)

Answer (score 0):

В контролере метод чуть отредоктирован:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/img/messages/{name}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public byte[] img(@PathVariable("name") String name, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    Optional<Message> messageSearchResult = messageRepo.findByFilename(name);

    if(messageSearchResult.isPresent()) {
        Message message = messageSearchResult.get();
        if (message.getImg() != null  && message.getImg().length > 0){
            byte[] img = message.getImg();

            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            response.setContentLength(img.length);
            response.getOutputStream().write(img);

            return message.getImg();
        }
    }
    
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Image Not Found");
}
```

Во view

```
<#if message.filename??>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/messages/${message.filename}" alt="Card image cap" style="width:100%">
</#if>
```

Ну и еще в application.properies добавить нужно было, чтобы картинка загружалась:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```